# Is good idea to deploy production server using docker in ups?

Tags: docker, deployment

I created a docker file that install my application for php and dependencies then use composer to install vendor packages all in docker container.

This container will link to MongoDB and Nginx to run.

It's ok for development but my question is it's ok to deploy my production env?

Consider in my production server I will install docker then run below command:

```
docker run --name MongoDB -d --rm mongodb:latest

docker run --name app --link MongoDb:mongodb -p 9000:9000 -d --rm myrepo/myapp:latest

docker run --link app:app --name Nginx --rm -d Nginx:latest
```

And then enter my `domain.com` and my production server using this dockers to run my app.
It's ok and stable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use docker compose to setup the three as services and deploy the whole thing as one stack using `docker-compose up`

See this [page](https://hellokoding.com/docker-compose-with-spring-boot-mongodb-nginx/) for a sample

Comment: My question is because I heard that docker is not stable for production if don't use cloud services like Kubernetes. @sxm1972

Comment: Whether docker is suitable for production environment or not is a very subjective question. I use it in production. Your needs may be different.